# Jquery - push multiple values in Array with index

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have this HTML with several  and same class ("traduction"):

```
<div>
    <div class="traduction" data-exist='yes' data-id-traduction="1">
        Blabla 1
    </div>
    <div class="traduction" data-exist='no' data-id-traduction="2">
        Blabla 2
    </div>
    <div class="traduction" data-exist='yes' data-id-traduction="3">
        Blabla 3
    </div>
    <div class="traduction" data-exist='no' data-id-traduction="4">
        Blabla 4
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need to have is an array like this:

```
array
    0
       content : 'Blabla 1'
       exist : 'yes'
       id : '1'
    1
       content : 'Blabla 2'
       exist : 'no'
       id : '2'
...
```

I tried with an array.push(values) but there isn't index in the array ...
How an I do please ?
thanks

Comment: can you show the code you tried and the output please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you mentioned [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) in your tags you can do this way for example:

```js
var myArray = [];
$( '.traduction' ).each( function() {
   myArray.push( {
     content: $( this ).text(),
     exist: $( this ).data( 'exist' ),
     id: $( this ).data( 'id-traduction' )
   });
});
console.log( myArray );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="traduction" data-exist='yes' data-id-traduction="1">
        Blabla 1
    </div>
    <div class="traduction" data-exist='no' data-id-traduction="2">
        Blabla 2
    </div>
    <div class="traduction" data-exist='yes' data-id-traduction="3">
        Blabla 3
    </div>
    <div class="traduction" data-exist='no' data-id-traduction="4">
        Blabla 4
    </div>
</div>
```

See the console for result output.